# Accommodating height of textbox WPF application

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox and listview inside a grid in WPF app. What I want is, when the text overflows inside the textbox, the listview height should  reduce accordingly to accommodate the textbox. Just like what happens in WhatsApp messenger when we type it in its textbox. 
Here's my code:

```
 <Grid MouseDown="ShowTextBox" Height="566" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,40,0" Background="White" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView MaxHeight="544" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" S Grid.Row="0"  Margin="20,0,0,0"  x:Name="sessionNotesList" />


            <TextBox  Grid.Row="1"  Height="Auto"  MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="554"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="20,0,30,12"  SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="sessionNoteContent" KeyUp="SaveNote" LostFocus="sessionNoteContent_LostFocus"  />


        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reversing the `Grid.RowDefinitions` so that the `ListView` takes all of the remaining space instead?:

```
<Grid MouseDown="ShowTextBox" Height="566" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,40,0" Background="White" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView MaxHeight="544" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" S Grid.Row="0"  Margin="20,0,0,0"  x:Name="sessionNotesList" />
    <TextBox  Grid.Row="1"  Height="Auto"  MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="554"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="20,0,30,12"  SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="sessionNoteContent" KeyUp="SaveNote" LostFocus="sessionNoteContent_LostFocus"  />
</Grid>
```